# IBM watson assistant always give Unauthorized error when try to use it

Tags: android, kotlin, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have been stuck for two days in a very strange issue in Watson Assistant

I have made some code to be able to use it in my app, it keeps giving me 401 authentications error

these are the three services that I have configured in my IBM cloud account

[image]

and here is my code to initialize the three service

```
private fun initSpeechToTextService(): SpeechToText {

        var options = IamOptions.Builder()
            .apiKey(getString(R.string.speech_text_iam_apikey))
            .url(getString(R.string.speech_text_url))
            .build()
        return SpeechToText(options)
    }

private fun initTextToSpeechService(): TextToSpeech {

        var options = IamOptions.Builder()
            .apiKey(getString(R.string.text_speech_iam_apikey))
            .url(getString(R.string.text_speech_url))
            .build()
        return TextToSpeech(options)
    }

private fun initAssistantService(): Assistant {

        var options = IamOptions.Builder()
            .apiKey(getString(R.string.watson_assistant_iam_apikey))
            .url(getString(R.string.watson_assistant_url))
            .build()

        var service = Assistant("2019-07-04", options)
        service.endPoint = getString(R.string.watson_assistant_url)

        return service
    }
```

my problem now that I always get status: 401, error: Unauthorized

can anyone please tell me what is missing?

**EDIT**

here are the urls that I am using

- https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api
- https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api
- https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api

**EDIT2**

here is a screenshot of my debugger windows

[image]

Comment: change the api key, or change the url, do you get the same error? (you need to work out if the error is in your code or if its config on the watson website side)

Comment: Off-course I did change the API keys, and I have tried many time I do not know exactly where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

The service version for your Assistant is set to `2019-07-04` which is invalid. Check here for the [latest and previous versions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-release-notes#release-notes). Does this work?

```
var service = Assistant("2019-02-28", options)
    service.endPoint = getString(R.string.watson_assistant_url)
```

Comment: @could you please check the urls that I am using, I edit my post

Comment: I have removed it and re created it again and now I am getting : Error getting IAM token from API